# How to source the files to be added to a git repo from a file?

Tags: linux, git

I want to always add the same files to my git repo, and I thought that having a file of files to add to git would be an easy way to do that.

How can I ask `git add` to read the files to be added from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also easy to use standard cli tools to do this :

```
# bash:
git add $(cat file)

# xargs is standard on linux, and comes with git-bash on Windows :
cat file | xargs git add
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `git add --pathspec-from-file=file` is just what I was looking for.

Just make sure that all lines are valid file names. And that none are empty.